# perl selenium: Test::Exception, proper usage and good code example?

Tags: perl, testing, selenium

In selenium IDE, the  code template installed by the perl driver/formatter includes a

```
use Test::Exception;
```

line of code by default.

I have a few question about this module wrt Test::WWW::Selenium.

**Should Test::Exception be used at all in my .t files?**

Until now I didn't use any methods from it and my tests run just fine (I usually do Happy-Path Testing).

Now I have come up with a potential use. I noted that the selenium object sometimes dies if it cannot find something on the page or if a locator is wrong, etc. In many cases I want my tests  to continue, i.e Selenium should not die, and continue to do things on a  page.

**Would this be proper usage of a Test::Exception Method?**
Should I try to combine it with Try::Tiny?

Here is a little helper method I just wrote.
The lives_and method belongs to Test::Exception.

```
sub verify_text_qr {
    my ( $sel, $text ) = @_;

    #$sel - the selenium object
    #$text ||= 'I think that'; # some text I am looking for on the page

     lives_and( sub { 
        my $found = $sel->get_text("//p[contains(text(), '$text')]");
        like( $found, qr /$text/) 
    }, 
        "found '$text' on page" );


}
```

*Edit - (question still unanswered- I just enhanced the method a little bit, making it more robust):*

```
sub verify_text_qr {
    my ( $sel, $text ) = @_;

    #my $text = 'Es ist unstrittig, dass ';
    my $found;
    lives_and(
        sub {
            try {
                $found = $sel->get_text("//p[contains(text(), '$text')]");
            }
            catch {
                fail( "cannot find '$text': " . $_ );
                $found = 0;
                note "on page " . $sel->get_location()  . ", " . $sel->get_title();
            };
            SKIP: {
                skip "no use in searching for '$text'", 1 unless $found; 
                like( $found, qr/$text/ ); # or $sel->like() ??
            }

        },
        "looked for '$text' on page"
    );

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not combine with [Try::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Try%3a%3aTiny), because [Test::Exception](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Test%3a%3aException) is catching it for you. Simple demonstration:

```
use Test::More;
use Test::Exception;

lives_and { is not_throwing(), "42" } 'passing test';
lives_and { is     throwing(), "42" } 'failing test';

done_testing;

sub not_throwing { 42 }
sub throwing     { die "failed" }
```

So I would use it similar way as your first snippet. You can also consider using [Test::Fatal](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Test%3a%3aFatal), which is somewhat more light-weight approach.

Comment: @daxim - I noticed that Moose recently went from T::E to T::F. Here is also some [rationale behind Test::Fatal by rjbs](http://rjbs.manxome.org/rubric/entry/1863)